# C++ Screenshot on mouse click does not work

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using Visual Studio 2017, I wrote code which should create a folder, capture a screenshot when the mouse button is pressed and save the screenshot to a .bmp file. But I don't know why that script does not work. Visual Studio compile it without errors / warnings.

Here is the code:

```
    // variable to store the HANDLE to the hook. Don't declare it anywhere else then globally
    // or you will get problems since every function uses this variable.
    HHOOK _hook;

    // This struct contains the data received by the hook callback. As you see in the callback function
    // it contains the thing you will need: vkCode = virtual key code.
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

    int filenum = 1;
    // This is the callback function. Consider it the event that is raised when, in this case, 
    // a key is pressed.
void TakeScreenShot(const char* filename)
{
    //keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    //keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    HBITMAP h;

    POINT a, b;
    a.x = 0;
    a.y = 0;

    b.x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    b.y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC     hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, abs(b.x - a.x), abs(b.y - a.y));
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, abs(b.x - a.x), abs(b.y - a.y), hScreen, a.x, a.y, SRCCOPY);


    // save bitmap to clipboard
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
    CloseClipboard();

    // clean up
    SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hScreen);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    h = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
    CloseClipboard();
    HDC hdc = NULL;
    FILE*fp = NULL;
    LPVOID pBuf = NULL;
    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader;
    do
    {
        hdc = GetDC(NULL);
        ZeroMemory(&bmpInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        GetDIBits(hdc, h, 0, 0, NULL, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        if (bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage <= 0)
            bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth*abs(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight)*(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount + 7) / 8;
        if ((pBuf = malloc(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage)) == NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Unable to Allocate Bitmap Memory"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            break;
        }
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        GetDIBits(hdc, h, 0, bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, pBuf, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        if ((fp = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Unable to Create Bitmap File"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            break;
        }
        bmpFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
        bmpFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
        bmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
        bmpFileHeader.bfType = 'MB';
        bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        fwrite(&bmpFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fp);
        fwrite(&bmpInfo.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, fp);
        fwrite(pBuf, bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, 1, fp);
    }

    while (false);
    if (hdc)ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    if (pBuf) free(pBuf);
    if (fp)fclose(fp);
}

LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        // the action is valid: HC_ACTION.
        if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            std::string OutputFolder = "C:\\temp";
            std::string filename = "ss";
            if (CreateDirectory(OutputFolder.c_str(), NULL) ||
                ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == GetLastError())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                // Failed to create directory.
            }
            auto numfile = std::to_string(filenum);
            TakeScreenShot((OutputFolder + "\\" + filename + std::to_string(filenum) + ".bmp").c_str());
            filenum++;
        }
    }

    // call the next hook in the hook chain. This is nessecary or your hook chain will break and the hook stops
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}



void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}


int main()
{
    // Don't mind this, it is a meaningless loop to keep a console application running.
    // I used this to test the keyboard hook functionality. If you want to test it, keep it in ;)
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

    }
}
```

If click with it does not make the directory (if it does not exist) and does not create the .bmp file.

Comment: You do check for some errors, but you do not take any action on error, and neither do you tell the user (or yourself) that there was an error. Reporting errors, and logging them verbosely, is very good if you can't otherwise debug your code.

Comment: The fact that code *compiles* means little to nothing regarding whether it *works* as intended (as you've found out). All "it compiles" means is "it's syntactically valid" - whether it is logically or semantically valid is still unknown.

Comment: The hook nowhere gets installed??

Comment: Apparently you forgot to call ` SetWindowsHookEx`. There may be more problems.

Comment: To learn how Stack Overflow works, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you never install your hook!  Also, it appears from my tests that you need to be dispatching messages to a window of some sort in order for a WH_MOUSE hook to get called.

Here's a minimal version of `main ()` that works for me:

```
int main()
{
    _hook = SetWindowsHookEx (WH_MOUSE, HookCallback, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId ());
    if (_hook == NULL)
        ...
    MessageBox (NULL, "Click OK to quit", "Screen Grabber", MB_OK);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx (_hook);
}
```

Then the rest of your code works fine, albeit is a little bit messy as others have said.

**However**, this will only catch mouse-clicks within the message box itself, and I don't think that's what you want.

If you want to catch these globally, you will need to install a "low level" mouse hook.  This needs to be a global hook but otherwise the code looks much the same.  The code to install and run the hook is:

```
int main()
{
    _hook = SetWindowsHookEx (WH_MOUSE_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        DispatchMessage (&msg);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}
```

Comment: Hello. I use your solution, but still does not create directory.

Comment: Which solution, the minimal version of `main` that I posted or the low-level hook stuff?  If it's the former, click on the message box!

Comment: Hey, in main, I use just declaration of _hook, but I don't want window app, I need globally it and as console app (or .dll to add to my script)

Comment: Updated my post - use the low level stuff

Comment: Thank you very much bro, but I have still one small problem. This screenshots has 1280x720px, I want fullscreen

Comment: Try setting `bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth` and `bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight` before the first call to `GetDIBits`.